# How to get the underlying Value from a Swift KeyPath when its type is KeyPath<Root, Value!>?

Tags: swift, swift4

Take a look at the following code:

```
struct Something {
  var s: String! // Implicitly Unwrapped Optional
}

func bind<T, V>(keyPath: WritableKeyPath<T, V?>) {
}

bind(\Something.s)
```

The code above does not compile. If we change the signature of `bind` to `bind<T, V>(keyPath: WritableKeyPath<T, V>)` then it *does* compile, but the problem is that the type of `V` is `String!` and I need to get the underlying type, in this case `String`.

We can solve the problem as follows:

```
func bind<T, V>(keypath: WritableKeyPath<T, ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<V>>) {
}
```

Unfortunately the documentation says that `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is deprecated. However, it is not marked as deprecated with the `@available` attribute.

I'm hesitant to use a type that the docs say are deprecated, but I can find no other way to accomplish what I need.

1. Is there another way to get the implicitly wrapped generic `Value` type from a `WritableKeyPath` when its type is `WritableKeyPath<T, V!>`?
2. Will `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` be removed at some point?

Comment: An implicitly unwrapped optional is still an `Optional`. Try replacing `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` with `Optional`.

Comment: @DennisVennink Unfortunately that doesn't work. In fact, if you look at my question carefully, you'll see I've already covered this case. `Optional<V>` and `V?` are the same type. Try it out in a playground. In most cases you're correct, but there's something different going on with Swift 4's KeyPaths.

Comment: My mistake. I see what you mean now.

Comment: Check out [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md). I'm not sure if `WritableKeyPath<Something, V!>` is a "nested IUO type", but those are not allowed from what I can tell with a quick skim.

Comment: Apple seems to have broken their own rule on this for keypaths.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5551. And yes, don't use `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` as a type – it's deprecated and Swift 5 will forbid it (https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12653).

Comment: @Hamish: Unfortunately I have no choice but to use it in this case unless you have a workaround. They will have to address this at some point.

Comment: @GregoryHigley You could define a forwarding computed property `var _s: String? { get { return s } set { s = newValue } }` and use that in your key path instead. But yeah, I suppose if you find that too verbose, `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` is your only option.

Comment: @Hamish I can't ask the users of my dependency injection framework to do that. It would be incredibly clumsy. The property injection stuff is still a work in progress: https://github.com/Prosumma/Guise/blob/injection/Guise/Bind.swift

Comment: @GregoryHigley Ah okay, well I guess you have your answer then :) Want me to write it up into an actual answer?

Comment: @Hamish Go for it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another way to get the implicitly wrapped generic `Value` type from a `WritableKeyPath` when its type is `WritableKeyPath<T, V!>`?

Not that I'm aware of. Really the problem here is that `\Something.s` *shouldn't* be a `WritableKeyPath<T, V!>`. That should be illegal under the rules set out by [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) (IUOs are attributes on declarations; they're not actual types that can satisfy generic placeholders).

Instead, `\Something.s` should be a `WritableKeyPath<T, V?>`, so really your original code ought to compile. This issue has been [filed as a bug here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5551).

> Will `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` be removed at some point?

Yes, this is set out by [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md):

> Because IUOs are an attribute on declarations rather than on types, the `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` type, as well as the long form `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` syntax, is removed. Types with nested IUOs are no longer allowed. This includes types such as `[Int!]` and `(Int!, Int!)`.

However the type-checker implementation for this wasn't fully implemented for Swift 4, which is why you're still able to use `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` as a type in order to work around your problem. [It has been implemented for Swift 5 though](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12653), so your workaround will no longer compile on its release.

Although hopefully the IUO key path bug will have been fixed by then.

Comment: When Swift 5 drops, I'll simply release a new version of my DI framework and _voilà_, problem solved. In fact, it should be as simple as removing the overloads that use `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`, since I already have overloads for `Optional`.